# Impact of using Flurry on Android

Tags: android, flurry

I am interested in using Flurry in a number of Android apps.

I have read various site and know how I want to Flurry. What I need to understand is the impact on performance of using Flurry.

Can someone point me to a resource which discuss this?

When calling the FLurryAgent does it run on its own thread? etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually FlurryAgent does use a thread:

DalvikVM[localhost:8630] (Suspended)
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended)
[...]
    Thread [<9> FlurryAgent] (Suspended)

[...]

Comment: Great, can you confirm all calls to FlurryAgent use their own thread? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I think you'd have to ask Flurry that question, but considering the way their API works, I believe it does.

Answer (score 0):

**Any** call to a Webservice should **not** be done on the main/UI thread. It's up to you to call the Flurry's registration method on another thread using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for instance.

**EDIT**

Indeed, `FlurryAgent` uses its own thread for all the calls. So  no need to use `AsyncTask`for that...

Comment: According to Absinthe FlurryAgent runs on its own thread, I might still make calls to FlurryAgent in a new thread to be safe

Comment: Ok didn't know about that. Just try it for yourself :)

Comment: @user964283 you really don't need to create a new thread. Your just generating overhead that way :)